# Overwriting operator new to merge PIMPL allocations

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, polymorphism, pimpl-idiom

The PIMPL idiom is often used for public API of objects which sometimes also contain virtual functions. There, a heap allocation is often used to allocate the polymorphic object which is then stored in `unique_ptr` or similar. A famous example of this is the Qt API, where most objects (esp. QWidgets and the like) get allocated on the heap and tracked by the QObject parent/child relation. Thus, we pay for two allocations, once the object itself with `2*sizeof(void*)` to hold the PIMPL and `v_table` pointer, and once the private data itself.

Now to come to my question: I wonder whether the two allocations could be merged, similar to the optimization applied by `make_shared`. Then I wonder whether this optimization is worth it, as implementations from `malloc` are potentially quite good at handling word-sized allocation requests. On the other hand, the positive cache-effects could be quite noticeable, i.e. having the private data allocated right next to the public object.

I played around with the following code:

---

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define debug(x)
#else
#define debug(x) x
#endif

class MyInterface
{
public:
  virtual ~MyInterface() = default;

  virtual int i() const = 0;
};

class MyObjOpt : public MyInterface
{
public:
  MyObjOpt(int i);
  virtual ~MyObjOpt();

  int i() const override;

  static void *operator new(size_t size);
  static void operator delete(void *ptr);
private:
  struct Private;
  Private* d;
};

struct MyObjOpt::Private
{
  Private(int i)
    : i(i)
  {
    debug(cout << "    Private " << i << '\n';)
  }
  ~Private()
  {
    debug(cout << "    ~Private " << i << '\n';)
  }
  int i;
};

MyObjOpt::MyObjOpt(int i)
{
  debug(cout << "  MyObjOpt " << i << "\n";)
  if (reinterpret_cast<void*>(d) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(this + 1)) {
    new (d) Private(i);
  } else {
    d = new Private(i);
  }
};

MyObjOpt::~MyObjOpt()
{
  debug(cout << "  ~MyObjOpt " << d->i << '\n';)
  if (reinterpret_cast<void*>(d) != reinterpret_cast<void*>(this + 1)) {
    delete d;
  }
}

int MyObjOpt::i() const
{
  return d->i;
}

void* MyObjOpt::operator new(size_t /*size*/)
{
  void *ret = malloc(sizeof(MyObjOpt) + sizeof(MyObjOpt::Private));
  auto obj = reinterpret_cast<MyObjOpt*>(ret);
  obj->d = reinterpret_cast<Private*>(obj + 1);
  return ret;
}

void MyObjOpt::operator delete(void *ptr)
{
  auto obj = reinterpret_cast<MyObjOpt*>(ptr);
  obj->d->~Private();
  free(ptr);
}

class MyObj : public MyInterface
{
public:
  MyObj(int i);
  ~MyObj();

  int i() const override;

private:
  struct Private;
  unique_ptr<Private> d;
};

struct MyObj::Private
{
  Private(int i)
    : i(i)
  {
    debug(cout << "    Private " << i << '\n';)
  }
  ~Private()
  {
    debug(cout << "    ~Private " << i << '\n';)
  }
  int i;
};

MyObj::MyObj(int i)
  : d(new Private(i))
{
  debug(cout << "  MyObj " << i << "\n";)
};

MyObj::~MyObj()
{
  debug(cout << "  ~MyObj " << d->i << "\n";)
}

int MyObj::i() const
{
  return d->i;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc == 1) {
    {
      cout << "Heap usage:\n";
      auto heap1 = unique_ptr<MyObjOpt>(new MyObjOpt(1));
      auto heap2 = unique_ptr<MyObjOpt>(new MyObjOpt(2));
    }
    {
      cout << "Stack usage:\n";
      MyObjOpt stack1(-1);
      MyObjOpt stack2(-2);
    }
  } else {
    const int NUM_ITEMS = 100000;
    vector<unique_ptr<MyInterface>> items;
    items.reserve(NUM_ITEMS);
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "fast")) {
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; ++i) {
        items.emplace_back(new MyObjOpt(i));
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; ++i) {
        items.emplace_back(new MyObj(i));
      }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (const auto& item : items) {
      sum += item->i();
    }
    return sum > 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -std=c++11 -g` the output is as one would expect:

```
Heap usage:
  MyObjOpt 1
    Private 1
  MyObjOpt 2
    Private 2
  ~MyObjOpt 2
    ~Private 2
  ~MyObjOpt 1
    ~Private 1
Stack usage:
  MyObjOpt -1
    Private -1
  MyObjOpt -2
    Private -2
  ~MyObjOpt -2
    ~Private -2
  ~MyObjOpt -1
    ~Private -1
```

But when you run it in valgrind, you'll see the following:

```
Stack usage:
  MyObjOpt -1
==21217== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21217==    at 0x400DC0: MyObjOpt::MyObjOpt(int) (pimpl.cpp:54)
==21217==    by 0x401200: main (pimpl.cpp:142)
==21217== 
    Private -1
  MyObjOpt -2
==21217== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21217==    at 0x400DC0: MyObjOpt::MyObjOpt(int) (pimpl.cpp:54)
==21217==    by 0x401211: main (pimpl.cpp:143)
==21217== 
    Private -2
```

This is the check I do to differentiate between a stack-allocated object and a heap-allocated object where I don't need to allocate the dptr anymore. **Any ideas on how to fix this**? The only way I see is introducing an ugly factory method.

I also wonder whether there is any way to overwrite the *whole* process of (de-)allocating an object, including calling its con/destructor. Then, one could simply call a different constructor from the overloaded operator new and be done with it...

---

Now let us look at whether it is worth it:

Compiled with `gcc -std=c++11 -O2 -g -DNDEBUG` I get the following results:

```
$ perf stat -r 10 ./pimpl fast

 Performance counter stats for './pimpl fast' (10 runs):

      9.004201      task-clock (msec)         #    0.956 CPUs utilized            ( +-  3.61% )
             1      context-switches          #    0.111 K/sec                    ( +- 14.91% )
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.022 K/sec                    ( +- 66.67% )
         1,071      page-faults               #    0.119 M/sec                    ( +-  0.05% )
    19,455,553      cycles                    #    2.161 GHz                      ( +-  5.81% ) [45.21%]
    31,478,797      instructions              #    1.62  insns per cycle          ( +-  5.41% ) [84.34%]
     8,121,492      branches                  #  901.967 M/sec                    ( +-  2.38% )
         8,059      branch-misses             #    0.10% of all branches          ( +-  2.35% ) [66.75%]

   0.009422989 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  3.46% )
```

---

```
$ perf stat -r 10 ./pimpl slow

 Performance counter stats for './pimpl slow' (10 runs):

     17.674142      task-clock (msec)         #    0.974 CPUs utilized            ( +-  2.32% )
             2      context-switches          #    0.113 K/sec                    ( +- 10.54% )
             1      cpu-migrations            #    0.028 K/sec                    ( +- 53.75% )
         1,850      page-faults               #    0.105 M/sec                    ( +-  0.02% )
    43,142,007      cycles                    #    2.441 GHz                      ( +-  1.13% ) [54.62%]
    68,780,331      instructions              #    1.59  insns per cycle          ( +-  0.50% ) [82.62%]
    16,369,560      branches                  #  926.187 M/sec                    ( +-  1.65% ) [83.06%]
        19,774      branch-misses             #    0.12% of all branches          ( +-  5.66% ) [66.07%]

   0.018142227 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  2.26% )
```

---

I assume that this microbenchmark is quite conceived, and it's a nice speedup of about factor 2. Nonetheless, the merged allocation could actually be very cache-friendly, compared to having two allocations such that the dptr is somewhere else alltogether.

Indeed, we can even see this:

```
$ perf stat -r 10 -e cache-misses ./pimpl slow

 Performance counter stats for './pimpl slow' (10 runs):

        37,947      cache-misses                                                  ( +-  2.38% )

   0.018457998 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  2.30% )

$ perf stat -r 10 -e cache-misses ./pimpl fast

 Performance counter stats for './pimpl fast' (10 runs):

         9,698      cache-misses                                                  ( +-  4.46% )

   0.009171249 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  2.91% )
```

Comments? Is there a way to get rid of the read of uninitialized memory in the stack-allocation case?

Comment: in `MyObjOpt::MyObjOpt(int)` you're using the value of uninitialized member `d`. That's UB.

Comment: You can solve all these problems and a lot more by replacing the pimpl machinery wholesale with abstract base classes and (smart) pointers that point to them.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes I know that I'm using an unitialized member - that's what valgrind is telling me as well. Of course that is UB, and that is why I ask on how to fix it...

Comment: @n.m.: can you give an example of that please?

Comment: I'm not sure I can quickly, google "pimpl vs abstract base class".

Comment: This is an interesting theoretical question, but I can't see any way with your current approach to make it legal code. That said I'm fairly sure 90ns per alloc/dealloc pair puts us in premature optimization territory: If time is really that important just trade the additional compilation time and de-pimpl the code.

Comment: @MarkB: Thing is, in large libraries like Qt this can be used in many places. And I don't thing that only the alloc/dealloc cost goes down - that is indeed arguably small. But the secondary effects thanks to better cache locality of an allocated public object and its private data might be quite noteworthy. Anyhow, without a way to figure out whether a given object is heap allocated or not, there is nothing I can do I fear :(

Answer (score 1):

I had my adventures long ago into optimizing pimpls, including using the Windows Thread Information Block to quickly determine if the outer object was on the stack or heap, and using something a bit like `alloca` with placement new and manual dtor invocations to construct and destroy pimpls.

There I was dealing with hotspots that related more to pimpl creation and destruction rather than the cost of access with reduced mem locality and indirection, but it was quite fast. It reduced the time to create an object with a cheap pimpl on the stack from about 400 clock cycles to 13 cycles because it eliminated the free store overhead outright. This was ages ago in the 90s: mileage may vary today.

*And I've regretted it ever since.*

It was one of those times where I felt like I became too clever, making the code too difficult to maintain and port and understand, even with generalized mechanisms to make it trivial and reusable for any object to subscribe to the system. It's just fighting the language design a little too much, wanting to balance high-level object constructs with the lowest-level assembly-type hacks.

Instead I would suggest to simply make your classes abstract enough to avoid mentioning implementation details to allocate subclass instantiations in one go. Example:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// In some public header:
// --------------------------------------------------------
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
std::unique_ptr<Interface> create_concrete();

// --------------------------------------------------------
// In some private source file:
// --------------------------------------------------------
// Include all the extra headers you need here 
// to implement the interface.

class Concrete: public Interface
{
public:
    // Store all the hidden stuff you want here. 
    virtual void foo() override {...}
};

unique_ptr<Interface> create_concrete()
{
    // Can use a fast, fixed allocator here.
    return unique_ptr<Interface>(new Concrete);
}
```

You get the same kind of pimpl benefits of hiding implementation details and creating compiler firewalls, but without losing the contiguous memory layout for the entire object. The downside is the abstraction cost of indirect virtual function calls, but that is almost always grossly overestimated. You'll often do immediately better trading the often negligible abstraction cost for the not-always-negligible benefits of better memory/cache locality.

If you need more than this, that's when I would suggest more C-like coding behind a good and safe public interface as a rare wildcard because it's actually a little bit easier to do low-level bit/byte memory management without worrying about object-oriented constructs getting in the way. I'd still recommend keeping such code behind a higher-level, safe C++ interface.

As for utilizing the stack, creating objects on the stack is super fast. So is a fixed allocator that allocates/deallocates objects in O(1) without a search (ex: a pool allocator treating memory chunks as a union between a buffer and a singly linked list pointer -- a list node when free, a buffer when occupied). You can get stack-like performance with such an allocator, and your objects will be close together in memory for spatial locality (especially if your allocation and deallocation patterns are in accordance with your utilization of the stack in which case the fixed alloc behaves like a virtual stack).

If you were already planning to utilize the stack anyway for such objects, you could make the fixed alloc just use a single pool with a predetermined size and branchless allocation and deallocation, truly rivaling the hardware stack (both in terms of efficiency and lack of safety against overflows and requiring a separate one for each thread). If you go this route, I recommend opting into this branchless allocator (with a separate function or overload) to use as a selective optimization detail. It's easier to avoid getting into trouble with semi-automatic optimization solutions than fully automatic.

Another thing you could do, and I didn't have this back then, is to use this new `std::aligned_storage` type. That requires you to anticipate the size of the pimpl in the header though, and I'd be tempted to make it larger than it actually is to leave some room for changes. I'd still recommend the abstract approach instead if you start becoming tempted to do this, as you don't want to start breaking ABI or fiddling with headers to add more to a pimpl.